# Создание базы VBA (Word)

Tags: vba, ms-word

Доброе, помогите реализовать идею.
В файле Word Есть UserForm в которой имеются TextBox (Фамилия, имя, отчество), так же две кнопки, "Добавить" и "База". Каким образом можно сделать что бы при нажатии кнопки добавить ФИО сохранялось в какой либо файл а при нажатии кнопки База открывается еще окно со списком ранее сохранённых ФИО при выборе ножного человека, TextBox заполняется выбранными данными.
Мне кажется что сохранять данные в EXcel файл а потом вытаскивать их оттуда довольно долгий процесс, какие есть варианты осуществить это быстро?
[Вот файл с примером.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14oVstIB9Cg5KBxSrhRY0_3wuRG43L4Ay/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Данные лучше хранить структурированно, Access или на худой конец Excel. Макросы позволят вам это сделать - покопайтесь в интернете [примеров](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/access/databases/)  много.

Но для этого вам нужно обладать минимумом знаний по базам данных. Эксель позволит без знания этих основ хранить/ находить данные, но при больших объемах и/или сложных данных будет неэффективен.
И еще, если нужно искать фамилии (либо другие данные) из какой-либо базы и вставлять их в готовую форму то Excel гораздо лучше приспособлен для этого. Он сохраняет конкретую структуру документа (бланка), каждое поле имеет координаты, которые легко менять с точностью до миллиметра.